# How to determine the values of rs, rd, and rt for MIPS instructions?

Tags: assembly, mips, machine-code, instruction-encoding

For example, the value of rs field for addi $t1, $t2, 20 is 01010. Why is that?

Comment: The first google hit for `i-type mips format` was https://max.cs.kzoo.edu/cs230/Resources/MIPS/MachineXL/InstructionFormats.html which goes through how to encode instructions.

Answer (score 1):

`$t2` is another name for $10.  01010 is binary for 10.